# websphere: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll] using spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, websphere

I get the following error...

```
Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll]
```

When adding ....

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/nonsecure/**" access="permitAll" />
```

I'm on Websphere with Spring 2.5.

Can anyone help?

Jeff Porter

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394657/spring-security-how-to-exclude-certain-resources/3394803#3394803

Answer (score 57):

you have to add *use-expressions* tag to your http configuration in security xml for example:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
...
...
</http>
```

Comment: This is the real answer !

Comment: BTW this configuration is done by default if you're using Java Configuration

Comment: Also don't use `auto-config` anymore : `A legacy attribute which automatically registers a login form, 
 BASIC authentication and a logout URL and logout services. If 
 unspecified, defaults to "false". We'd recommend you avoid using 
 this and instead explicitly configure the services you require.
` from https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/schema/spring-security/3.2.0.RC2/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd

Answer (score 9):

To be able to use expressions such as [permitAll] you have to add a a [WebExpressionVoter to your AccessDecisionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web)