# Spring Security: how to exclude certain resources?

Tags: spring-security

I have the following definition...

```xml
    <bean id="fsi" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
      <sec:filter-invocation-definition-source >
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/css/**"        access="ROLE_TIER0"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/images/**"     access="ROLE_TIER0"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"                   access="ROLE_TIER0"/>
      </sec:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

I'd like to have the resources on this url...

"/nonSecure/**"

Open to all calls, i.e. no security around it.

I've tried adding ...

```xml
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/nonsecure/**" access="permitAll" />
```

But this causes Websphere to throw an error about

```
Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll]
```

Can anyone tell me how to exclude this URL from security?

Comment: You should consider to accept enyo answer because old Gandalf approach is no longer supported.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In spring security 3.1.x the use of filters="none" is deprecated. Instead you use multiple `<http>` tags like this:

```xml
<http pattern="/nonsecure/**" security="none"/>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic

Comment: This was deprecated in a minor release? Incredible!

Answer (score 24):

I think you have to add `use-expressions` tag to your `http` configuration in security xml for example:

```xml
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
...
...
</http>
```

Edit:
Well I am not sure what version of spring security you are using. I know this works on 3.0 but for older versions I am not sure.

Comment: Beware using the attribute `auto-config`--I just learned that the hard way.  From the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-namespace): "Use of this attribute is not recommended."

Answer (score 19):

```xml
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/getfeed/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

access="**IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY**" Is the solution.
I found it on the following link http://syntx.io/adding-http-basic-auth-to-restful-services-in-java-and-spring/

Intercepts are evaluated top down. If you write this /** before /getIntelFeed/** then all service would go through /** and security would be applied on all services. In such case /getIntelFeed/** would be ineffective.

Comment: I added the `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` for my `intercept-url pattern` entry. However, I got a 401 error when trying to access the pattern url. Why would that be? Note that I followed your "intercepts are evaluated top down" caution.

Comment: Please review the link in post for details. If you are facing issues even after following link then please share your code.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead :/

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```xml
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/nonsecure/**" filters="none" />
```

Comment: I agree with this answer in general; however, one common issue with filters="none" that people often miss is that without Spring Security filters in the chain, there is NO SecurityContext, thus non-obvious security checks (e.g. service-layer annotations or JSP custom tags referencing Spring Security objects) may unexpectedly fail. Be careful if you are using filters="none" on pages with dynamic content!

Comment: filters="none" is no longer supported in Spring 3.1

Comment: does `filters="none"` skip custom filters as well?

Comment: ```org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate <http> element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'"```

Comment: IntelliJ also gives an error about this, but we are using spring-security 3.1 without problems and with this attribute, which is still correct according to the official docs at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e3264

Comment: while filters="none" is now deprecated, there is an equally useful equivalent in security="none" (see enyo's answer)

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use expressions such as [permitAll] you have to add a a [WebExpressionVoter to your AccessDecisionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web)

Comment: Specifying use-expressions in the http tag does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the rest of your configuration, and since it looks like you have explicit bean configuration, it's hard for us to guess exactly how you have things configured. I'll say that some combination of the above answers is correct.

1. If you are using Spr Sec 3, Gopi's answer is correct if you want to enable SpEL expressions (and have the corresponding beans which can evaluate them also configured). This can be hard if you are not using the http namespace.
2. If you have an appropriate filter configured for setting up a SecurityContext for unauthenticated (anonymous) users, then setting role="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" or some combination thereof should work.
3. If all else fails, as several folks have suggested, filters="none" will do what you want, but take care that you *really* don't need anything to do with Spring Security in the code underlying the pages you are rendering, otherwise you may find yourself scratching your head later on.

Good luck!