# Retrieve Spring Security's Authentication, even on public pages with filter="none"

Tags: java, spring-security

Let's say I have a simple page called faq.html. I want this page to be publicly accessible, so I apply the usual Spring Security configuration:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/faq.html" filters="none" />
```

Let's also say that if the user reaches this page after authenticating, I want to print "Hi Firstname Lastname" on the page. For pages that require authentication, I simply put [the result of the following](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1518) into my `ModelMap`, and then the names are accessible in my view later:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

This doesn't work for `faq.html`, presumably because when you specify `filters="none"`, then the call to `getPrincipal()` returns null. (This behavior makes sense since the configuration causes no filters to be applied.) So, instead it seems that I have to do a bunch of the Spring Security stuff manually:

```
public static Authentication authenticate(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, SecurityContextRepository repo,
        RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    // try to load a previous Authentication from the repository
    if (auth == null) {
        SecurityContext context = repo.loadContext(
                new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response));
        auth = context.getAuthentication();
    }

    // check for remember-me token
    if (auth == null) {
        auth = rememberMeServices.autoLogin(request, response);
    }

    return auth;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? For example, it seems like Spring should provide some facility for hooking their API calls in via the original `<sec:intercept-url />` config.

Comment: Note that `filters="none"` seems to have been deprecated in Spring 3.1.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5382178/521799

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the reason not to use `filters = "none"` for public pages.

Use `access = "permitAll"` instead (or `access = "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"` if you don't have `use-expressions = "true"`).

Comment: Rock on. I wasn't aware of that option.