# Spring mvc static resource configuration issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, tomcat7

I am working with spring mvc 3 on tomcat 7.  I have been having issues getting my static resources to load.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-static
 -common
  - paths to static
- WEB-INF
```

I have already made sure that the statics were not getting caught up in a request mapping I have set up.  However, whenever I go to retrieve them I just get a 404 as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/YouthMinistryHibernate/static/common/css/compiled.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8080/YouthMinistryHibernate/static/common/js/compiled.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>YouthMinistryHibernate</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC --> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>simple</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>deepDishCMSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
            <param-value>simple</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>deepDishCMSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my spring-mvc config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="message" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>image/jpeg</value>
                        <value>image/png</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

I have tried retrieving the resources using two methods:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${ pageContext.request.contextPath }/static/common/css/compiled.css" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/static/common/js/compiled.js" />"></script>
```

Here is the link to the project on github as well just in case:
http://github.com/dmcquillan314/YouthMinistryHibernate

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the relevant configuration in my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/build.sh</executable>
            <arguments>
                <argument>${env}</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceExcludes>static/common/js/**</warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java-version}</source>
            <target>${java-version}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <warName>YouthMinistryHibernate</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <url></url>
            <server>TomcatServer</server>
            <path>/YouthMinistryHibernate</path>
        </configuration>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

Debug logs when I try to access this resource:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/static/common/js/compiled.js]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/static/common/js/compiled.js] are [/static/**]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/static/common/js/compiled.js] are {}
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/static/common/js/compiled.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@569939c1] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/YouthMinistryHibernate/static/common/js/compiled.js] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [common/js/compiled.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/static/]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'deepDishCMSServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**UPDATE**

Still have not fixed this issue however, I've had the chance to look through all of my codebase and found nothing helpful so far.  At the moment I'm looking around to see where my code may be getting stuck.

I'm thinking the issue may lie somewhere in the spring mvc config as it doesn't seem to be using the mvc:resources when loading in the static file request mappings.  My mvc config is below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

    <!-- Add controller package to be scanned for this path -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.youthministry.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>image/jpeg</value>
                        <value>image/png</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you set a `context.xml` for your application, or a final name inside pom? If not, the context name is `YouthMinistryHibernate-${pom.version}`

Comment: I've updated the post with the relevant information from the pom.xml

Comment: What's in the log when you try to access the static urls? Set `logger.org.springframework.web.servlet` logger to `DEBUG` and paste the output.

Comment: @soulcheck I've added the debug logs to the bottom of my post

Comment: Which branch of your git repo has those static resources, cause i can't see them there?

Comment: @soulcheck I just synced the remote repo up with my local.  My current code with statics is located in the feature.content-components branch

Comment: Could it be getting caught up in spring security somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed.  I resolved it by making a few modifications to simplify the mvc, security and web.xml configurations.  It seemed to be getting caught up in spring security somehow.

Comment: @StephaneEybert It ended up being a conflicting filter that was filtering the static resources.  I simply just added a filter to spring security to not disallow access to that route.  here's where I found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394657/spring-security-how-to-exclude-certain-resources