# My css files don't get loaded

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc

I'm going crazy why my css file isn´t getting loaded. I'm using `spring mvc 4` + `apache tomcat 8`

I already use the same code for other projects and it works normally.
Here's my project structure

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>AO</display-name>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>hibernate.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

my servlet context :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/RESOURCES/**" location="/RESOURCES/" />  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

when he try to load :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css" >
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/AO/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css">
```

i got this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/AO/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css 404 (Introuvable)
```

Comment: try this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css">`

Comment: How about this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css'/>"

Comment: no also it doesn't work

Comment: can you post the resulting html output of your page?

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394657/spring-security-how-to-exclude-certain-resources

Comment: the page load correctly but without css `GET http://localhost:8080/AO/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css 404 (Introuvable)`

Comment: did you add  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd to your schemalocation?

Comment: yes i did but i solved the problem by just deleting and adding again apache tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Delete the Apache tomcat server and I add it again and finally my CSS has been loaded :)
Can somebody explain me why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> to your mvc configuration file.

Comment: It makes it possible to map the spring mvc dispatcher servlet to "/" and yet have the container serve static resources. It is actually an alternative to using <mvc:resources /> as far as I can tell. Now that it did not help, is the RESOURCES folder actually being copied over to Tomcat upon deployment?

Comment: How can i know if it is deployed ?

Comment: Go and have a look at the WAR file or deployment directory and see if the RESOURCES directory is there.

Comment: I Delete the Apache tomcat server and I add it again and it finally my CSS has been loaded :)
Can you explain me why ?

Answer (score 0):

change the mapping for RESOURCES to LOWERCASE `resources`

Except the name of your Application,which can contain Uppercase elements, the path for resources must contain only lowercase

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/RESOURCES/" />
```

Then ref :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/welcome.css" >
```

Comment: I Delete the Apache tomcat server and I add it again and it finally my CSS has been loaded :) Can you explain me why ?

Comment: it is working for me and for sure nothing is wrong with the tomcat server... maybe you don't know how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[c:url](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html)</kbd> tag of  [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) to make the URL relative.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel=stylesheet href="<c:url value='/RESOURCES/css/welcome.css'/>" 
      type="text/css" />
```