# Failing to exclude some URLs from Spring Security protection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have the following spring security configuration:

```
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="***.JsonAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="***.web.security.***UrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="redirectStrategy" ref="noRedirectStrategy"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
          class="***.web.security.***UrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <bean id="httpStatusEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="UNAUTHORIZED"/>
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" entry-point-ref="httpStatusEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter"/>

        <security:form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"/>
        <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,sessionId"
                         success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"
                />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="concurrentSessionFilter" class="***.***ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="***SessionRegistry"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="errorController"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
                <ref bean="concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="***SessionRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy" class="***.web.security.***ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="***SessionRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg name="logoutService" ref="logoutService"/>
        <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- enable spring security annotation processing -->
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <bean id="***LdapAuthenticationProvider" class="***.web.***LdapAuthProvider">
        <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}"/>
        <property name="filter" value="${ldap.filter}"/>
        <property name="domain" value="${ldap.domain}"/>
        <property name="dn" value="${ldap.dn}"/>
        <property name="ldapEnabled" value="${ldap.enable}"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="***LdapAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="***UserDetailsService"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="usersResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg value="/users.properties" />
    </bean>

    <util:property-path id="usersResourceFile" path="usersResource.file" />

    <bean id="***UserDetailsService" class="***.web.security.***InMemoryUserDetailsManager">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="usersResourceFile"/>
    </bean>
```

I tried different ways But I can not find a way to exclude some specific URLs from authentication.

For example:

```
/api/url/available/without/login
```

should be available even user is not logged in.

### P.S.

I have tried to apply this answer, but it doesn't work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5382178/2674303

### UPD

I have tired

```
    ....
    <bean id="httpStatusEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="UNAUTHORIZED"/>
    </bean>
    <security:http pattern="/api/url/available/without/login" security="none"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" entry-point-ref="httpStatusEntryPoint">
    ....
```

but when I try to use - this url still locked and I get 401

because this code:

```
 SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
 Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
 if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
       String name = authentication != null ? authentication.getName() : "";
       throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not find user " + name);
  }
```

throws exception

Comment: The linked answer should work, did you put the `<http pattern="xxxx" security="none"/>` above your `security:http auto-config="true"`?

Comment: @RC I have updted topic

Comment: can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: @RC.  What do you mean about stack trace?  I don't see exception

Comment: @RC. org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException

Comment: **SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            String name = authentication != null ? authentication.getName() : "";
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not find user " + name);
        }**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a "default" http interceptor:

```
<security:http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll()"/>
  <anonymous/>
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

after your current security:http tag. It will handle all requests, which were not handled by the first http construction.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute |Offending resource: class path resource [context-security.xml]

Comment: Well, try to add
 
    <http-basic/>
into `security` tag

Comment: but what if I want to exclude 5 urls. Should I add 5 new security:http tags ?

Comment: No, the first security:http tag handles requests to `/api/**` only. The second "default" http tag handles all others requests. You will need to add new http tags in case if you want to protect some new URLs (and then you need to place these new https tags before "default").

Comment: actually works if add **security:http** tag with specific url **BEFORE**  **security:http**tag with  /api/**

Comment: /api/url/available/without/login mathes as /api/**

Comment: please show code. You say No, but it sounds as Yes according my opinion